# Check if document.getElementById does not exist?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking at the tutorial here:

https://www.detectadblock.com/

This is the Javascript they use to detect is Adblock is enabled:

```
if(document.getElementById('APvpIfBTxbcQ')){
  alert('Blocking Ads: No');
} else {
  alert('Blocking Ads: Yes');
}
```

I don't have any code that needs to be run if someone is not blocking ads.

So, this line is basically useless to me:

```
alert('Blocking Ads: No');
```

What would I need to change to remove that part and basically do this?

```
if(document.getElementById('APvpIfBTxbcQ') IS NOT SET){
  alert('Ads are being blocked.');
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test if the opposite of something is true you just put the not (`!`) symbol in the front of it.

```
if(!document.getElementById('APvpIfBTxbcQ')){
  alert('Ads are being blocked.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a latest browser, you can do something like this:

```js
console.log("Ads blocked: " + (document.querySelector("#ad-id") === null));
console.log("Ads blocked: " + (document.querySelector("#ad-id-2") === null));
```

```html
<div id="ad-id">Hi</div>
```

In the above code, the `ad-id-2` is not present. So you can essentially compare it with `null`.

To be completely sure, you may want to check if the ad is really displaying. You can do using [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123999)

In your original code, you can also use `!!` to make sure.

```
if (!!document.getElementById('APvpIfBTxbcQ')) {
  alert('Blocking Ads: No');
} else {
  alert('Blocking Ads: Yes');
}
```